# Matlab For loop with if statement

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have an (6x 2)array the name of that array is xVertBT{n}.con(x,y) and the X0all(18 x 3) each time each time I am getting x01(x,y,z) and x02 (x,y,z). So I am using this statement X0all((xVertBT{n}.con(i,1)),:) to check if that is the same with x01 or x02 .
For that I am getting an error Index exceeds matrix dimensions

```
for i=1:6%size(xVertBT{1}.con,1)

if isequal(X0all((xVertBT{n}.con(i,1)),:),(x02)) || isequal(X0all((xVertBT{n}.con(i,1)),:),(x01));
    for j=1:6

    if isequal(X0all((xVertBT{n}.con(j,2)),:),(x01)) || isequal(X0all((xVertBT{n}.con(j,2)),:),(x02));
    epsC=0.7;
        return
    end
    end
end
```

end

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using the debugger to see where your indices grow out of bounds? It would be much easier for us to tell what's going wrong if you included a full [mcve] with sample values for all of the variables.